# Remove System.Runtime from application insights custom metrics

Tags: .net, azure-application-insights, metrics, background-service, azure-monitoring

I am only logging one custom metric (not shown).  The rest all seem to come from System.Runtime.  I'm using `.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` and dependency injecting `TelemetryClient`.  How can I stop my service from emitting all these custom metrics from System.Runtime?  I am concerned because they cost money.

[image: Custom Metrics]

Answer (score 0):

I disabled this option and it no longer emits those events.

```cs
.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(options =>
{
    options.EnableEventCounterCollectionModule = false;
})
```